# Test if any item in a list is part of another list of strings

Tags: python, string

Imagine I have a list of key-words:

```
terms = ["dog","cat","fish"]
```

And I also have another list that contain longer strings of texts:

```
texts = ["I like my dog", "Hello world", "Random text"]
```

I now want that I have a code that basically goes through the list `texts` and checks if it contains any of the items in the list `terms` and it should return a list that contains if this item in texts had a match.

This is what the code should produce:

```
result = ["match","no match","no match"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `zip()` and a list comprehension:

```
terms = ["dog","cat","fish"]

texts = ["I like my dog", "Hello world", "Random text"]

results = ["match" if a in b else "no match" for a,b in zip(terms,texts)]

print(results)
```

Output:

```
['match', 'no match', 'no match']
```

---

**UPDATE: Turns out the zipping wasn't what the OP wanted.**

```
terms = ["dog","cat","fish"]

texts = ["I like my dog", "Hello world", "Random text"]

results = ["match" if any(b in a for b in terms) else "no match" for a in texts]

print(results)
```

Output:

```
['match', 'no match', 'no match']
```

Comment: thats almost what I need, but if the order of the terms changes it does not work anymore. Meaning it should still find the "match" if the word "dog" is last in the term list.

Comment: I would use set methods for simplicity. Unfortunately, I'm in the middle of cooking dinner and can't write up an example for an answer.

Comment: I hope your dinner goes better than my own solutions to that question and I hope you might find some time later. :))

Comment: @paul_on_pc Updated.

Comment: LOL Thx. I say 'unfortunately' because I suspect someone else will jump all over this chance before I get back.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Thats what it is. Thanks to Ann Zen. Now our friend user10637953 can eat without rush.

Comment: Well Done Ann! More than one way to flip an aardvark, I guess. = )

Comment: Follow Up: My idea turns out to be longer than Ann's because I must go through the process of splitting out the words in texts before using >> results = ["match" if a in set(texts) else "no match" for a in set(terms)] What set() does for us is eliminate duplicates here, nothing more. Ann's zip() method is better.